# Как отправить запрос из поисковой строки в API

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

прилагаю код из HTML части сайта, отвечающий за само поисковое окно

```
<div class='search'>
 <form>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="search" name="search" onkeyup="myFunction()" size="50">
    <input type="submit" value="search" onclick="alert('click')">
  </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, если Вы использовали слово "прилагаю", то вы хотели к вопросу добавить еще и Ваш код? И, возможно, стоит более явно задать и сам вопрос?

Comment: Добавьте атрибут action форме с значением url-адреса, на который она должна отправится. А так же по необходимости метод, которым будет отправляться запрос (GET, POST...).